# Spring MVC configuration and mapping

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Hate to ask a simple config question but I'm new to the spring mvc framework and for some reason struggling a little bit.  I am working on this just to learn it as I have used MVC in ruby and wanted to try it in java.

I have a sample app that talks to a DB and returns a full table from my controller out to a JSP it all works my table is displaying from the DB Correctly.  I still think I have my configs wrong though as my app only works if my web.xml is setup like so

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>foo</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/RunList.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I don't think I should have to use the full name of the JSP in my pattern.  if I just use /  I get

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>foo</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

Sep 01, 2015 10:53:02 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/dyn-qa-qeb/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'foo'
```

Here is my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/RunList")
public ModelAndView listRun(ModelAndView model) throws IOException{
    //@ModelAttribute
    System.out.println("**** Controller ******");

    List<QAModel> listRun = runDao.list();
    model.addObject("RunList", listRun);
    model.setViewName("RunList");

    return model;
}
```

I also have an MVC Configuration file that I setup based on a tutorial but I am not sure if that just overrides the web.xml

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.foo")
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

     @Bean
        public ViewResolver getViewResolver(){
            InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
            resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
            resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
            return resolver;
        }

        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
        }
```

Comment: I would love some suggestions here if anyone has ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a config issue long ago solved just cleaning up my questions